# How can I find all stored procedures, functions, etc. that have a temp table with column(s) that are shorter than the db column populating them

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-schema, temp-tables

We heavily use SQL Server and probably have more than 1500-2500 stored procedures alone. I have been dealing with a ton of what I would call novice level mistakes lately doing maintenance work for our application.

I find frequently that people have have defined a column in the temp table that is shorter that the db column being queried which causes truncation errors when executed under certain conditions. The same goes for a data type mismatch because SQL Server cannot implicitly convert them but that is very infrequent for me.

In our software we never take a segment of original data and put it in the shorter length temp table like LEFT(Name, 25) etc so the assumption is that any column in a temp table that is shorter than its populating tables column is wrong (in my specific company).

Is there any way to scan all database objects for temp tables that have a mismatched set of table definitions?

An example is something like this though I'm sure you all know what I mean

```
CREATE TABLE #TNames (
     First varchar(35),
     Middle varchar(1),
     Last varchar(35)
);

INSERT INTO #TNames
    SELECT  
        First, --Names.First is varchar(35) YAY!!!!
        Middle, --Names.Middle is varchar(35) BOO!!!! Bad developer, shame on you for #TNames.Middle varchar(1) 
        Last --Names.Last is varchar(35) YAY!!!!
    FROM 
        dbo.Names
```

Comment: Rather than checking all the db objects, why not create temp tables based on actual table schema? Something like this -   
`Select * into #temp from dbo.Names where 1=0;`
That way even if table changes in future, you don't have to make any change to your code.

Comment: If it was me, I would do that in simple cases. We have hundreds  of stored procedures that are more complex inserts from many tables into a single temp table. Probably the majority are that way actually.